# Validate Finnish IBANs

Tags: beginner, haskell, functional-programming

I am currently studying an online course in Haskell and there are no "model examples" of the assignments after finishing them. I'm slowly getting the hang of this, but I'd like some feedback on how could I have written this differently. This piece of code took me a lot of hours to finish, but it works now!

I am especially curious whether I could've done the replace' function in a better way!

The assignment was as follows:

> Write a function `validate :: String -> Bool` that, given a string validates the string as a Finnish IBAN code.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Validating_the_IBAN) explains the validation rules.

And some additional rules for Finland:

1. The length of a Finnish IBAN code is 18
2. Finnish IBAN begins with the country code FI.
3. All the characters after the country code are digits.

```
validate :: String -> Bool
moveCharsToEnd :: String -> String
isDigit :: Char -> Bool
onlyDigits :: String -> Bool
replace' :: String -> String

--Replaces the country code FI with 1518 at the beginning of the string.
replace' xs | x <- xs = '1':'5':'1':'8' : drop 2 xs

isDigit c = c >= '0' && c <= '9'

--Takes the first 6 (4) characters and puts them to end of the string.
--6 because I have converted FI to 1518, so that's two additional chars.
moveCharsToEnd x | x <- x = drop 6 x ++ take 6 x

--Checks whether given list consists only of digits.
onlyDigits [] = False
onlyDigits [s] = isDigit s
onlyDigits (x:xs)
    | isDigit x = onlyDigits xs
    | otherwise = False

--Validates the IBAN according to rules.
validate x
    | y <- x, length y == 18,
    (y !! 0 == 'F' && y !! 1 == 'I'),
     onlyDigits (tail (tail y)),
     ((read (moveCharsToEnd(replace' y)) :: Integer) `mod` 97 == 1) = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Comment: There's no need to repeat tags in the title or to say you're looking for feedback, so I've removed those for you.  I hope you get some good answers from people who actually know Haskell!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since you're using Haskell, I'm guessing you *want* the compiler to be picky with you. using the `-Wall` flag is a good idea; there's some discussion about how to take this even farther [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/sxpchd/til_about_wunusedpackages/).
- It's normal to put type declarations with their corresponding definitions. I see the intuition of having them all at the top, but it's not the convention.
- Using `-Wall` points out that in `replace'` and `moveCharsToEnd`, you've bound unused variables, but I think the problem is slightly deeper than that. Why are there pattern guards there at all? Neither of them are doing anything.
- Import the `isDigit` function from `Data.Char`. It's in `base`, so you're not adding a dependency by doing this.
- `onlyDigits = all isDigit` is clear enough that it no longer needs a comment explaining what it does. [`all`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) is from `Prelude`.
- In `validate`, pattern-matching `y <- x` is pointless; it can't fail and there's no reason not to use the already bound `x`. (Even if you did just want to bind a new variable, use a `where` or `let` clause for that.)
- There are a couple places where [`splitAt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) can help you break up the string into it's semantic chunks.
- I don't think there's a way for your use of `read` to crash the program as it's written now, but I would still suggest against doing that. If that were to fail you'd get a runtime exception instead of `False`, which is bad!. There are a few ways you can rewrite that clause using [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe); I'll show how I imagine *you* might do it.
- Chaining together a bunch of boolean guards with `,` isn't something I've seen before. I would suggest negating them all, mapping each to `False` separately, and then have `| otherwise = True`.

All that gets us this far:

```hs
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

--Replaces the country code FI with 1518 at the beginning of the string.
replace' :: String -> String
replace' xs = '1':'5':'1':'8' : drop 2 xs

--Takes the first 6 (4) characters and puts them to end of the string.
--6 because I have converted FI to 1518, so that's two additional chars.
moveCharsToEnd :: String -> String
moveCharsToEnd x = let (prefix, rest) = splitAt 6 x in rest ++ prefix

onlyDigits :: String -> Bool
onlyDigits = all isDigit

--Validates the IBAN according to rules.
validate :: String -> Bool
validate x
    | length x /= 18                     = False
    | country /= "FI"                    = False
    | not (onlyDigits digits)            = False
    | Just i <- asMInt, i `mod` 97 /= 1  = False
    | Nothing <- asMInt                  = False
    | otherwise                          = True
    where (country, digits) = splitAt 2 x
          asMInt = readMaybe (moveCharsToEnd(replace' x)) :: Maybe Integer
```

This is basically the same as what you wrote, give or take some tiny performance differences. That said, this doesn't seem like a case to be worrying about performance at all; worry about *clarity* and *maintainability*. In other words, make sure your code mirrors the validation instructions exactly, and make it modular if possible. You have a lot of logic that's specific to the case of Finland; I suggest writing a completely agnostic base validation, and then layering the Finland stuff on top.

This is quite different from what you wrote, sorry, I'm just procrastinating on my own homework:

```hs
import Data.Char (toUpper)
import qualified Data.Ix as Index
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

type CountryCode = String  -- should probably be a newtype!

finland_CCode :: CountryCode
finland_CCode = "FI"

countryLengths :: [(CountryCode, Int)]  -- I don't think base has a hashmap.
countryLengths = [(finland_CCode, 18)]

alpha_R :: (Char, Char)  -- range definitions
alpha_R = ('A', 'Z')  -- assume uppercase most places; coerce at the begining.
num_R :: (Char, Char)  -- range definitions
num_R = ('0', '9')

isAlphaNum :: Char -> Bool  -- this is stricter than Data.Char.IsAlphaNum
isAlphaNum c = Index.inRange alpha_R c || Index.inRange num_R c

ibanIntRepresentation :: String -> Maybe Integer
ibanIntRepresentation iban = (concat <$> (asDigits `mapM` rearranged)) >>= readMaybe
  where (prefix, rest) = splitAt 4 iban
        rearranged = rest ++ prefix
        asDigits :: Char -> Maybe [Char]
        asDigits c | Index.inRange num_R c = Just [c]
                   | Index.inRange alpha_R c = Just $ show $ 10 + (Index.index alpha_R c)
                   | otherwise = Nothing

-- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Validating_the_IBAN.
validateIBANBase :: String -> Bool
validateIBANBase iban
  | maybe False (length uppercase /=) countryLength                 = False
  | not (all isAlphaNum uppercase)                                  = False
  | maybe False (not . checkMod) (ibanIntRepresentation uppercase)  = False
  | otherwise                                                       = True
  where uppercase = toUpper <$> iban
        countryCode = take 2 uppercase
        countryLength = lookup countryCode countryLengths
        checkMod i = i `mod` 97 == 1

-- Specifically validates a Finnish IBAN.
validate :: String -> Bool
validate iban
  | not (validateIBANBase iban)             = False
  | country /= finland_CCode                = False
  | not (all (Index.inRange num_R) digits)  = False
  | otherwise                               = True
  where uppercase = toUpper <$> iban
        (country, digits) = splitAt 2 uppercase
```

As a final note, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#National_check_digits) says there's additional check-digit logic for Finland, but this is outside my expertise.